# How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop

Tags: javascript, function

I want to define helper methods on the Array.prototype and Object.prototype. My current plan is to do something like:

```
Array.prototype.find = function(testFun) {
   // code to find element in array
};
```

So that I can do this:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var found = arr.find(function(el) { return el > 2; });
```

It works fine but if I loop over the array in a `for in` loop the methods appear as values:

```
for (var prop in arr) { console.log(prop); }
// prints out:
// 1
// 2
// 3
// find
```

This will screw up anybody else relying on the `for in` to just show values (especially on Objects). The later versions of javascript have .map and .filter functions built into arrays but those don't show up on `for in` loops. How can I create more methods like that which won't show up in a `for in` loop?

Comment: That is just the reason for *not using for-in loops on arrays*!

Comment: [Don't modify objects you don't own.](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's quite easy: Don't use [for-in loops with Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572). Blame everybody else who does so - [here is a nice snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11507509/1048572) to tell them during development.

Of course, if one does an enumeration in a generic function and doesn't know whether he gets an array, a plain object or an object with a custom prototype, you can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) like this:

```
for (var prop in anyObj )
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(anyObj, prop))
        // do something
```

Notice the explicit use of `Object.prototype` to get the function - there might be objects that overwrite it (especially in data-maps, the value might not even be a function), objects that [do not support it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8157700/1048572) or objects that do not inherit from Object.prototype at all. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13240607/1048572).

Yet, only a script author who is aware of the problem would filter all his for-in-loops - and some only do it because [it gets recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1107681/1048572) - and does it mostly wrong, he should have used a for-loop array iteration instead. But our problem are those authors who do not know of it.

An interesting, but Mozilla-only approach would be overwriting the behavior of enumerations on arrays via [`__iterate__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Iterators), as [demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1809873/1048572).

Fortunately, EcmaScript 5.1 allows us setting properties to be *non-enumerable*. Of course, this is not supported in older browsers, but why bother? We'd need to use [es5-shims](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) anyway for all the cool higher-order array stuff :-) Use [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "find", {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    value: function(testFun) {
        // code to find element in array
    }
});
```

Comment: I like putting that long hasOwnProperty in a helper function. Having a shorthand like `hop(anyObj, prop)` makes me less likely to use one of the shorter but suboptimal alternatives that you mentioned.

Comment: Sure, you can define `var hop = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty)`, but as the average programmer should never need it I've not mentioned this. Those libraries which provide highly generic functions use it internally, of course.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your restrictions:

```
// In EcmaScript 5 specs and browsers that support it you can use the Object.defineProperty
// to make it not enumerable set the enumerable property to false
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'find', {
    enumerable: false,  // this will make it not iterable
    get: function(testFun) {
       // code to find element in array
    };
});
```

Read more about **Object.defineProperty** here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

Comment: No, you don't want to define a getter function for this prototype method. Have a look at my answer...

Comment: You can't trust anyone else using your code will do the hasOwnProperty check, so this is a safe way.

Answer (score 2):

The above answers miss a point:

> enumerable ... **Defaults to false**. ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty))

So simply using `Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'myFunc' myFunc)` instead of `Array.prototype.myFunc = myFunc` will resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's because have to check for `hasOwnProperty`:

```
for (var prop in arr) { 
  if (arr.hasOwnProperty(prop)) { 
    console.log(prop) 
  }
}
```

Now this logs 1, 2, 3.

Comment: bergi was trying to say that this code breaks if someone adds a "hasOwnProperty" property to arr or its prototype.

Comment: Really bad advice