# Adding json stringify to the javascript object prototype

Tags: javascript, json, serialization

I'd sure like to be able to add this:

`Object.prototype.toJson = function() {
    this.toJson = undefined;
    return JSON.stringify(this);
}`

But it gets all circular reference-y.  I still want to be able to write .toJson() all over the everywhere.

Comment: Maybe with out that this.toJson = undefined in there.  That was messing around that ended up in my clipboard.

Comment: Just drop the `this.toJson = undefined;`...what are you trying to accomplish with that?

Comment: Without it still yeilds:
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON 
it was a lame attempt to make that go away.

Comment: Just tested this in the console of chrome, and it works fine here. `Object.prototype.toString = function() {return JSON.stringify(this);};var j = {a: 'b'};j.toString()` yields `"{"a":"b"}"` in the console window.

Comment: The basic `Object` contains references to itself that `JSON.stringify()` can't resolve.  You need to make sure the data structure you are are trying to encode is a valid data structure for encoding.

Comment: @nclu: Can you please show us on what object you tried `.toJson()`? Probably it just *has* a circular reference.

Comment: Don't forget to have a look at [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296340/how-to-define-method-in-javascript-on-array-prototype-and-object-prototype-so-th)

Comment: Seems to work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/UfZmr/1/

Comment: The error actually seems to come in when other libraries are later loaded.  Moment.js and KendoUI both are triggering the circular reference.  At this point I'm thinking that modifying the Object prototype isn't a very good idea.  It'd be nice if objects could just serialize themselves and handle circularity in some magical elegant fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems to [work fine](http://jsfiddle.net/UfZmr/1).

```
Object.prototype.toJson = function() { this.toJson = undefined; return JSON.stringify(this); }
```

> The error actually seems to come in when other libraries are later loaded. Moment.js and KendoUI both are triggering the circular reference. At this point I'm thinking that modifying the Object prototype isn't a very good idea. It'd be nice if objects could just serialize themselves and handle circularity in some magical elegant fashion