# Determine if the object has a property and value in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I wanted to check if the an object has a property of something and its value is equal to a certain value.

```
var test = [{name : "joey", age: 15}, {name: "hell", age: 12}]
```

There you go, an array of objects, now I wanted to search inside the object and return true if the object contains what I wanted.

I tried to do it like this:

```
Object.prototype.inObject = function(key, value) {
if (this.hasOwnProperty(key) && this[key] === value) {
  return true
};
return false;
};
```

This works, but not in an array. How do I do that?

Comment: this[i][key] would of course be the array syntax for i = 0 and 1 in your case

Comment: have you tried a loop on array.length? Then you can use this[i][key], etc.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the [`some` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to test your function for each value of the array:

```
function hasValue(obj, key, value) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === value;
}
var test = [{name : "joey", age: 15}, {name: "hell", age: 12}]
console.log(test.some(function(boy) { return hasValue(boy, "age", 12); }));
// => true - there is a twelve-year-old boy in the array
```

Btw, [don't extend `Object.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296340/how-to-define-method-in-javascript-on-array-prototype-and-object-prototype-so-th).

Comment: @Ecropolis: but trivially shimmable, see the "polyfill" section of the linked docs

Comment: @poepje Oh right. Never certain in written communication, especially with so many newbies around who might pose this as a serious question. Now pointed out, the humour is obvious...

Answer (score 6):

-- for the property --

```
if(prop in Obj)  
//or
Obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)
```

-- for the value ---

Using  "Object.prototype.hasValue = ..." will be FATAL for js but **Object.defineProperty** let you define properties with  **enumerable:false** (default)

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype,"hasValue",{
   value : function (obj){
              var $=this;
              for( prop in $ ){
                  if( $[prop] === obj ) return prop;
              }
              return false;
           }
});
```

just for experiment test  if a NodeList has an Element

```
var NL=document.QuerySelectorAll("[atr_name]"),
    EL= document.getElementById("an_id");
console.log( NL.hasValue(EL) )  

// if false then #an_id has not atr_name
```

Comment: This is the most useful answer I've found for checking an object for a value, and the only one that explicitly mentions the fatal javascript error that many people will encounter.

Answer (score 4):

For array, of course you have to browse that array with `for`

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < yourArray.length; i++){
    if(yourArray[i].hasOwnProperty("name") && yourArray[i].name === "yourValue") {
     //process if true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll use something like `Object.first`:

```
// search for key "foo" with value "bar"
var found = !!Object.first(test, function (obj) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty("foo") && obj.foo === "bar";
});
```

Assuming that `Object.first` will return some falsy value when it doesn't find a match.

`Object.first` is not a native function but check on of the popular frameworks, they're bound to have one.

Comment: Never heard of `Object.first`. Do you mean `Array.first`?

Comment: I guess I meant `Object.find`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution for checking if the object has the property but the value of property is not set. Maybe the property value has 0, null or an empty string.

```
array.forEach(function(e){
 if(e.hasOwnProperty(property) && Boolean(e[property])){
  //do something
 }
 else{
  //do something else
 }
});
```

Boolean() is the trick here.