# jQuery tmpl if object value == current iteration value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

SelectedPlayersI'm doing some work on a site which is using jQuery templates.

I have a JSON object:

```
var data = [{
   "CoachingSessionActivityID": 1,
   "PlayersInTeams": [{"PlayerID": 1, "PlayerName": "Some Name"},{"PlayerID": 2, "PlayerName": "Another Name"}],
   "SelectedPlayers":[{"PlayerID": 1, "PlayerName": "Some Name"}]
},{
   "CoachingSessionActivityID": 2,
   "PlayersInTeams": [{"PlayerID": 1, "PlayerName": "Some Name"},{"PlayerID": 2, "PlayerName": "Another Name"}],
   "SelectedPlayers":[{"PlayerID": 1, "PlayerName": "Some Name"}]
}];
```

I'm trying to mark a select option (powered by Bootstrap-Multiselect) as selected if the current iteration PlayerID is in the selected players object.

```
 <select id="playersList_${CoachingSessionActivityID}" class="form-control players-list"  multiple="multiple" name="playersList">
                    {{each(PlayerID, PlayerName) PlayersInTeams}}
                        {{if checkForValue(SelectedPlayers == PlayerID)}}
                            <option value="${PlayerID}" selected="selected">${PlayerName}</option>
                        {{else}}
                            <option value="${PlayerID}">${PlayerName}</option>
                        {{/if}}
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
```

I'm using this function to identify whether a player is within the selected list:

```
 function checkForValue(json, value) {

            for (key in json) {
                if (typeof (json[key]) === "object") {
                    return checkForValue(json[key], value);
                } else if (json[key] == value) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

**Problem**

The problem is only **1** item is being identified as being a selected value. Our actual data has 150 players in "PlayersInTeams" and some coaching sessions have over 20 selected players.

Any ideas?

Comment: because you are ending the function operation when a condition is true.You need iterate the complete list.Why you call the same function as chain?

Comment: Shouldn't `{{if checkForValue(SelectedPlayers == PlayerID)}}` be `{{if checkForValue(SelectedPlayers, PlayerID)}}` else it'd pass a boolean to the function?

Comment: Sorry you're right Ishettyl , I was doing that. I just hacked into my code to remove sensitive data and forgot to fix it for the post. 

That's a good point @ARUNRAJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arunraj was right, my function was ending when it returned true obviously so it wasn't iterating the complete list.

I found the answer from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19302725/1888402

Essentially using `obj.some(...)` with the following function:

```
function hasValue(obj, key, value) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === value;
}
```

In the scope of the question, the solution was:

```
  {{each(PlayerID, PlayerName) PlayersInTeams}}
      {{if SelectedPlayers.some(function(player){ return hasValue(player, "PlayerID", PlayerID)}) }}
           <option value="${PlayerID}" selected="selected">${PlayerName}</option>
      {{else}}
           <option value="${PlayerID}">${PlayerName}</option>
       {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
```