# Is obj.hasOwnProperty(key) really required when iterating objects to be IE compatible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

To be IE compatible we decided to use classic `for` loop for arrays:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) { ... }
```

and adding `obj.hasOwnProperty(key)` for object `for` loops:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    ...
}
```

But... Is this really required?

I remember that I looked in the jQuery source code and I didn't find this condition when iterating objects.

Also, if the answer is *yes*, is there any shorter solution than adding `if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;` to every object iterating? I mean to rewrite `for` somehow...

To be clear: if instead of `for (var k in o) { ... }` I would use:

```
foo (o, function (k) {
   ...    
});

function foo (o, callback) {
    for (var k in o) {
        callback (k);
    }
}
```

I would just add the `if` only one time, in `foo` function. But consider having a lot of object `for` loops. Is there any solution to rewrite `for`?

Comment: @Teemu Why isn't it required? Why will it fail?

Comment: @Teemu I use regular for lop for arrays, but for objects I think that `in` is required. (see how my question starts)

Comment: If you're only iterating objects that you yourself created, and you don't add anything to the prototype of Object, the object shouldn't contain any values that would cause issues, and then there's no need to check if the the objects hasOwnProperty.

Comment: that's why i like Object.keys(obj).forEach()...

Comment: @dandavis Now, it's too late. I would like to add few lines in a script and to make all for blocks that don't use `if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;` compatible with IE.

Comment: @イオニカビザウ note that this has **nothing** to do with Internet Explorer. The `.hasOwnProperty()` check is a good idea in **all** browsers (if you're not using `Object.keys()`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
  function foo(o, callback) {
    var i, k = Object.keys( o );
    for (i = 0; i < k.length; ++i)
      callback(o[k[i]], k[i]);
  }
```

Note that you *probably* should be passing the *value* at each key to the callback, and not just the key. If you just want to iterate through an object without a helper function, then, it's:

```
var keys = Object.keys( obj ), value;
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
  value = obj[ keys[ i ] ];
  // ...
}
```

`Object.keys()` returns an array, so you can use array-style iteration with an index.

The `Object.keys()` function doesn't exist in older browsers, but you can use a pollyfill like [the one at the MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). The function does not return inherited properties, so no `.hasOwnProperty()` test is needed.

If you're 100% sure that your code is never going to run in a context where other code has modified the prototype objects of various built-in (and, for that matter, non-builtin) constructors, then you don't need to worry about `.hasOwnProperty()`.  However, since the bugs that such problems introduce are usually pretty serious and weird, it's probably worth checking.

*edit* — fancier version:

```
function foo(o, callback) {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(function(k) { callback( o[k], k ); });
}
```

Comment: I don't have a `foo` function. I have a looot of for loops that iterate objects. `if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key) continue;` works fine, but the question is if is there any shorter solution?

Comment: @イオニカビザウ well I just used that for the example.  The point is that with `Object.keys()` you don't have to call `.hasOwnProperty()` because it already effectively does that check for you..

Comment: That's true, but still this doesn't answer to the second part of the question: *how can we rewrite for?* I don't have a function like `foo`, so that means to edit each for block...

Comment: @イオニカビザウ I thought it was clear, but I'll add more to the answer.

Comment: I think I am not clear enough... :-) Imagine that I have to edit 3000 for loops. I would like to add few lines in a js file and to make all 3000 for loops IE compatible without edit them. Is this possible?

Comment: @イオニカビザウ No, that is not possible.  That's why it's actually a good idea to write code with things like you're fictional "foo" function instead :)  The `in` operator works the way it works, in other words, and you cannot change that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43676/discussion-between---and-pointy)

Answer (score 2):

It's not required.

Just make sure to code [array loops correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/1048572) and [not to vandalize prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13296897/1048572). Attention is only required when you have horribly coded third-party modules which you cannot omit.