# JavaScript mixin to combine Object and Class creates TypeError

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, mixins

I am trying to combine an existing object with a class that extends it (and its prototype).

The code is below, I can of course add more detail if needed but I think this covers the problem. As specified amongst the code, the error is `TypeError: this.prototype is undefined`. The last line in this snippet is the call which causes this error, the error itself occurs in the .addMixin(mixin) function.

The references I have used to get here include:
http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/javascript-mixins-functional-inheritance/ and
http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html (though this was a stepping stone to reach above)

Note: I know this can be done with JQuery and other libraries but I want to do this Vanilla.

```
// setup some tools
var config = {
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
};

var defineProperty = function(obj, name, value) {
  config.value = value;
  Object.defineProperty(obj, name, config);
}

// And mixins
Object.prototype.addMixin = function (mixin) {    
    for (var prop in mixin) {
        if (mixin.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            this.prototype[prop] = mixin[prop]; // this is where the error occurs: 'TypeError: this.prototype is undefined'
        }
    }
};

// Define File prototype
var File = Object.create(Object.prototype);
defineProperty(File, 'file', null);
defineProperty(File, 'outputID', null);
defineProperty(File, 'hash', null);
defineProperty(File, 'hashThis', function (callback) {});

// define Timestamp prototype
var Timestamp = Object.create(File);
defineProperty(Timestamp, 'protectedHashValue', null);
defineProperty(Timestamp, 'timestamp', null);
defineProperty(Timestamp, 'read', function () {});
defineProperty(Timestamp, 'verify', function () {});

// Later, we take in a file using the HTML5 file API
// First, create the File object (in an array because there are multiple files)
globalStatus.files[fileIndex] = Object.create(File);
// and now place the file in the file property of the new File object
globalStatus.files[fileIndex].file = evt.target.files[fileIndex];

// Later on we determine that a particular file is a timestamp
// We want to mix in the properties of the Timestamp prototype to this existing File object
globalStatus.files[fileIndex].addMixin(Timestamp); // this is the call which initiates the error
```

Comment: Well, the `File` instance that is placed in your array (on which you call the `addMixin` method) does not have a `.prototype` property. Why do you expect it to do?

Comment: [Do not mess up `Object.prototype`!](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Comment: When you mix classical inheritance and prototypal inheritance you are asking for troubles. But if you really want to shoot yourself in the foot try this.constructor.prototype.

Comment: Why are you using that obscure `defineProperty` method if you could simply use dot notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `addMixin` method `this` refers to an object instance, on which the method was invoked. 
Instances do not have a `prototype` property - `Function`s do.

I am not exactly sure, what you are trying to do: to add mixin properties to all future instances or to add them to an instance, so I'll provide you with both variants.

For all instances, what you need to use is a `constructor` property, which returns a function, that was used to create an instance:

```
Object.prototype.addMixin = function (mixin) {    
    for (var prop in mixin) {
        if (mixin.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            this.constructor.prototype[prop] = mixin[prop]; 
        }
    }
};
```

For a specific instance, simply use bracket notation on `this`:

```
Object.prototype.addMixin = function (mixin) {    
    for (var prop in mixin) {
        if (mixin.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            this[prop] = mixin[prop];
        }
    }
};
```

Beware of properties of `mixin` parameter, that are reference types (e.g. `object Object` or `object Array`)

Comment: Yes, meant to change that specific instance. Your answer makes good sense, this is my first time doing properly OOP JavaScript.

Comment: How do you feel about adding the Mixin function to Object.prototype? Bergi does not like/recommend it.

Comment: @user2700751: I'm fine with it, but you need to make it non-enumerable (via `Object.defineProperty` which you already know).

Comment: @user2700751 Bergi is right. Another option is to implement your own base class with `addMixin` method and inherit from it, not from `Object` directly.