# Extending Javascript Arrays prototype with Max/Min to find values

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototypal-inheritance, prototypal

Looking at different methods of how to find max/min values in Javascript Array I can often see extending prototype of Array object itself. So having:

```
var a=[22,33,44,32,1];

Array.max=function(v) { 
    return Math.max.apply(this,v); 
};

Array.max(a); // returns 44
```

However I often do as below:

```
Array.prototype.max=function() { 
    return Math.max.apply(this,this); 
};

a.max(); // returns 44
```

This allows me to call max() with no parameters on the Array object itself. Personally I don't see any problem with it and I keep wondering if am I missing something and this method has some major problems I overlook? Is it safe to use as `Array.max(arrayhere)`?

EDIT: Is it correct to say that in first example we creating static method on native Javascript Array object and in second example we extending Arrays prototype?

Comment: `this` depends on how you call the function. You're calling it without a context, then it defaults to `window`. You're second example should be on the `prototype`.

Comment: Yes, I apologise, I meant to type in Array.prototype.max rather than Array.max. I edited the code now

Comment: And your first example should be on `Array` directly…

Comment: @Bergi, you totally right, edited again, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that in first example we creating static method on native Javascript Array object and in second example we extending Arrays prototype?

Yes.

> Personally I don't see any problem with it and I keep wondering if am I missing something and this method has some major problems I overlook?

Some people who use `for in` on arrays might trip over your enumerable `max` method. While I personally think that they deserve it, [one can play safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

> Is it safe to use as `Array.max(arrayhere)`?

Yes, it avoids the enumerability concern. However, you still need to consider that [extending javascript natives has its own problems](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/extending-javascript-natives/), see also [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572). If you chose the static approach anyway, putting them on your own library object instead doesn't complicate anything.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is using `Object.defineProperty` or `Object.defineProperties`. In this case I'll write how to do it with the latter. ***Edit: Note this will not handle empty arrays as you would expect. See edit below.**

```
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
    max: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function () {return Math.max(...this)},
    writable: true
  },
    min: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function () {return Math.min(...this)},
    writable: true
  }
});
```

Then you can just do:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1].max() // 4
[4, 3, 2, 1].min() // 1
```

This will prevent anyone from tripping into the `for in` gotcha, as you set those properties enumerability as false.

### EDIT. Handling empty arrays

As @MikeM point out in his comment, the [documented behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) of `Math.max()` and `Math.min()` is probably not what makes more sense –at least for me–. If you don't send arguments to those functions, you get `Infinity`, with a different sign in each case:

```
Math.max(); // -Infinity
Math.min(); // Infinity
```

Therefore, if the array we're calling `.max()` or `.min()` on is empty, we'll get an arguably not-so-reasonable result. To handle that edge case, the solution would be:

```
Object.defineProperties(Array.prototype, {
    max: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function () {
            if (this.length === 0) return null; // or whatever makes more sense
            return Math.max(...this)
        },
    writable: true
  },
    min: {
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
    value: function () {
            if (this.length === 0) return null;
            return Math.min(...this)
        },
    writtable: true
  }
});
```

Comment: `[].max()  // -Infinity`

Comment: I didn't know that JS weirdness. Good catch @MikeM!