# For in loop extra output?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-in-loop

Sorry this is a very small segment of code:

```
var arr = [2,4,6,8];
var obj = {};
for (var i in arr) {
    obj[arr[i]] = arr[i] * 2;
}
```

What I expect it to do is output the values of `arr` in an object, and return those values doubled.  My does that but also includes this:

```
'function () {\r\n  var result = [];\r\n  for (var property in this)\r\n    result.push(property);\r\n  return result;\r\n}': NaN
```

Can anyone explain to me why this happens?  Thank you.

Comment: You're using the wrong kind of loop for an Array. Use a `for` statement instead. What's going on is that either `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype` has been extended with a method. Because `for-in` enumerates all enumerable properties, even when inherited, you're including the method in the loop.

Comment: ...it looks like a loose version of `Object.keys`, so it's probably on `Object.prototype`.

Comment: You totally messed up the OOP approach, `i` is property of `arr` but you are using it as index.. Either use a full for loop `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)` or use `obj[i] = i * 2`

Comment: …which makes this related to [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Comment: @Mahmud: I think that's what he intends. He wants the result to be `{"2":4, "4":8, "8":16, "16":32}`

Comment: @cookiemonster Oh I see... then he can try using `eval` if its conflicting with some prototype