# How to add a new method to root class object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to add a new method named size to object class in javascript.

```
var obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
object.prototype.size = function() {
var obj=this;
var size = 0, key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
};

console.log(obj.size());
```

The obj is typeof object, I add new function for object as object.prototype.size=function(){}

But when I run it, the firefox give me error:

```
ReferenceError: object is not defined (line 10)
```

you can view the code here:(http://jsbin.com/cisasewo/1/edit)

When I change the method to:

```
Object.prototype.size = function() {
var obj=this;
var size = 0, key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
};
```

when it invoke, it just give me the function not the answer the size of the function? 
why? how to add the size function to object class in javascript?

Comment: How are you invoking the 2nd function?

Comment: You're not calling it as a function. You need the () after size

Comment: Notice that you shouldn't be doing this, [or at least do it correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13296897/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second implementation is correct. You just need to change

```
console.log(obj.size)
```

to

```
console.log(obj.size())
```

Comment: There is no `console.log` in the method implementation. `console.log(obj.size)` is a valid statement and will not cause the given error.

Comment: @zerkms Look at the jsbin link

Comment: look at the error message on jsbin. As you may find - it has nothing to do with a function call and will persist if you remove the whole `console.log` line

Comment: @zerkms it's a valid statement but it's exactly what's causing the output in the 2nd part of the post

Comment: "but it's exactly what's causing the output" --- remove the `console.log` line and check that it's not http://jsbin.com/cisasewo/4

Comment: @zerkms Actually both problems exist

Comment: there is no "both" problem. There is one - the wrong `object` name

Comment: @zerkms So console.log(obj.size) is invoking the size method?

Comment: it's not. It would output a reference to a function. OP doesn't have problems with that at all. OP didn't ask about how to invoke a method, since they presumably know that

Comment: Which is exactly what the poster was experiencing in the 2nd part where they were using the correct Object with capital O

Comment: Oh god, I did not expect someone would implement JS inheritance without knowing how to call a function :-S

Comment: Well I was simply telling them that their 2nd implementation was correct and they (presumably) made the silly mistake of missing the brackets

Comment: Indeed, +1 and dropping my answer. It's silly that question code doesn't match the jsbin one

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be work like this way:

```
Object.prototype.size = function() {
var obj=this;
var size = 0, key;
for (key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) size++;
}
return size;
};

var t = new Object();
t.a = 1;
alert(t.size());  ///result is 1 because property a is defined
```