# JavaScript: Assign values of arguments object as fields in an Object

Tags: javascript, oop

I am currently converting an Object constructor from the form of

```
function Obj(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, ..., argN-1, argN) {
  this.name = arg1;
  this.field = arg2;
  this.etc = arg3;
  ...
} //Obj
```

to the form of

```
function Obj() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  var defaultArgs = {
      'field'  :  default
      ...
  };

 ... check args, etc

 } //Obj
```

Here is my code so far:

```
function DSObj () {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  var defaultArgs = {
  'fields' : values or functions returning values
  ...
  };

  var options = {};

  for (var i in defaultArgs) {

    if (typeof(args[i] == 'undefined')) { 
      options[i] = defaultArgs[i]; 
    } else { 
      options[i] = args[i]; 
    } //check if the user supplied this argument
  } //for each possible argument

  for (var name in options) {
    this.name = options[name]; //trying to make fields - obviously wrong
  } //for each final parameter
} //constructor for DSObj
```

So, what I need help with is the last part of the above constructor. I just started programming JavaScript around a week ago, and my education goes about as far as reading a beginners syntax book. So, if there is a better way to do this other than the stupid and direct way, please let me know. The reason that I can't just reference the options array above is that all of the methods written for this object in some way use the "this.method" paradigm. Please. Guise. Help.

Comment: Try `this[name] = options[name]`. With Javascript objects, you can treat indexes like object properties.

Comment: This cant work, as `args` is an array with integer keys and `defaultArgs` is an object with non-numeric keys. You wouldn't find any `i` in both.

Comment: `if (typeof(args[i] == 'undefined'))` will always return `true`, since `(args[i] == 'undefined')` will return a boolean, which `typeof` will convert to the string 'boolean', and any string evaluates to true. You probably want `if (typeof args[i] == 'undefined')`.

Comment: @KodleeYin—that's because indexes **are** object properties. :-)

Comment: Thanks Guys! All very good feedback. I will try out your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need bracket notation instead of dot one:

```
for (var name in options) {
    this[name] = options[name];
}
```

Be aware that `for...in` loops iterate inherited properties, you may want to check `options.hasOwnProperty(name)` to avoid that.

Also note that when you iterate `defaultArgs`, `i` is each property. But `args` is indexed with numbers, not you custom keys.

You can use something like

```
function DSObj () {
  var argNames = ['fields', /*...*/],
      defaultArgs = [ /* ..., ... */];
  for (var i=0, l=arguments.length; i<l; ++i) {
      this[argNames[i]] = arguments[i] || defaultArgs[i];
  }
}
```

Or if `arguments[i]` can be falsy, then

```
this[argNames[i]] = arguments[i] !== void 0 ? arguments[i] : defaultArgs[i];
```

Comment: `defaultArgs` was initialised with an object literal, there are no custom prototypes. We can safely assume that there are no inherited enumerable properties, a `hasOwnProperty()` test is unnecessary.

Comment: @Bergi Maybe another script modified `Object.prototype`. But yeah, it can be unnecessary, it was just a warning.

Comment: Then it would be that script's fault [if it's not done correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572). You shouldn't need to care.

Comment: Thanks, the first part worked exactly how I thought it should. It's amazing how flexible JavaScript can be. As for the code suggestions -- I was given code that originally had something similar, so the modificiations you suggested make my life easier.