# Attaching underscore to Object prototype, bad idea?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, ecmascript-5

The common wisdom is the just because you **can** augment native types, doesn't mean you **should**.

That augmenting a native types prototype is a bad idea **always**, with the only exception being to polyfill behavior that is within the ECMAScript Spec.

In our project we're using underscore quite a bit and I was wondering, why not use the OOP style it provides directly on our objects?

```
var _ = require('underscore');
Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, '_', {
    get: function() {
        return _(this);
    }
});
```

Which enables us to use underscore methods directly like so, without having to make the decision to require the library everywhere we want to use it, but to simply know it's there and standardize on using underscore functionality when appropriate.

```
[1, 2, 3]._.contains(3); // true

var funcOnce = function() {
   console.log("hello");
}._.once();

funcOnce(); // "hello"
funcOnce(); // 

{one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}._.keys(); // ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

I believe I've limited the scope of the damage by only modifying a single (probably useless `_`?) property on the native Object.

Can you see how this will come back to bite us in developing our application, assuming there is never a native `_` property introduced in `Object`?

Comment: I can't help but look at `}._.keys();` (along with all the other chained methods) and chuckle.

Comment: I'd have to double-check, but I imagine that this would mess up basic stuff like `for in` loops on objects, which many third-party vendors probably assume are safe to use.

Comment: Okay, I checked, and at least that particular concern isn't a problem.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior - That was my first thought as well. Although while testing I was not able to reproduce the for in issue and am now a little unsure if it would overlap or not. I believe that the reason it will not overlap is because I was thinking of prototypal inheritance as opposed to simply defining a property on the Object prototype.

Comment: @Luxelin haha, that did actually come up in discussing this with the team :D    I'll call that an advantage.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you see how this will come back to bite us in developing our application, assuming there is never a native `_` property introduced in Object?

Yes. While you have [avoided that the property shows up in `for in` loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572), you did forget to provide a setter. And this will definitely hunt you:

```
// let's start with this
Object.defineProperty( Object.prototype, '_', {
    get: function() {
        return "sorry";
    }
});
// now what do you expect the following statements to do?

> var x = {}; "_" in x;
true // meh, obvious
> var x = {_:"works"}; x._
"works" // this is hijackable in older browsers!
> var x = {}; x._ = "works"; x._
"sorry" // well…
(function(){"use strict"; var x={}; x._ = "works"; return x._; }())
unhandled TypeError: "Invalid assignment in strict mode" // ooops!
> _
"sorry" // ah, window._ inherits from Object.prototype as well
> _ = "works"; _
"sorry" // and prevents even simple global variable assignments
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `require` to get the underscore dependency, which *could* give you a number of advantages (supposing you use it right), like:

1. freedom to load the dependency asynchronously, on-demand, and
2. the ability to use different versions of the dependency in different parts of your code

If you're going to start using underscores on objects, you lose these advantages, the same way you would if you just used underscore as a global variable. And, to what end? So you can replace

```
_([1, 2, 3]).contains(3)
```

with

```
[1, 2, 3]._.contains(3)
```

?

It may not be a Bad Idea™, but it doesn't seem like a particularly good one, either.

Comment: Fair enough, we use browserify, so really it just saves us from having to go through the cognition of,  "Do I REALLY need to require underscore in this part of the code for this ONE thing?" and then have that whole internal debate, "I guess I COULD do this without it".