# How to extend Obect.prototype correctly?

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I'm writing a JavaScript  Library that offers the function `tablify(anything);`, which is able to represent any Array or Object as an HTML Table.

Now I'm trying to extend the Array and Object prototypes in order to  use it like this:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var obj = {"A": "a", "B": "b", "C": "c"};
arr.tablify();
obj.tablify();
```

This is my approach:

```
Array.prototype.tablify = function() {
    return tablify(this);    
}
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'tablify', {
    value: function () {
        return tablify(this);
    },
    writable:     true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable:   false
});
```

The issue is, that everything in JavaScript is an Object and therefore not only literals like `{a: 1, b: 2}` can be converted, but also everything else.

This wouldn't be such a big deal since my `tablify()` can also deal with primitive types, but when I extend Object.prototype, `typeof anything` always returns `"object"` and I can't distinguish between types anymore:

```
function tablify(object) {  
    if (object instanceof Array) {  
        return ArrayToTable(object);
    } 
    //This is always true if I extend Object.prototype: 
    if (typeof object === "object") {   //only for "normal" objects like "{a: 1, b: 2, c: [],...}"
        return ObjectToTable(object);
    }
    return PrimitiveToTable(object);    //strings, numbers, functions, ... 
}
```

- Why is `typeof` always returning `"object"`?
- Is it a good thing for a JS-API to provide this sort of functionality (extending Arrays/Objects with ".tablify();")?
- How is it possible to distinguish between "normal" objects, numbers, functions,... ?
- Is it possible to only extend "normal" objects?
  (forbid `(42).tablify();`, `"string".tablify();` ...)
- Whats the name for those "normal" objects? How should I call them?

Comment: A function that creates HTML from an object doesn't sound like something you'd generally want to add to the native Objects prototype ?

Comment: It is not true that "everything in JavaScript is an object".  Strings, numbers, and booleans are not objects. They do *act like* objects in situations where they're called upon to do so, because the language implicitly converts them to a corresponding object type.

Comment: @Pointy When I use my code, `42.tablify();`, `"string".tablify();`, `func.tablify();` are working too, although I only extend Object.prototype. And the `typeof` returns `"object"` as well...

Comment: Yes, because JavaScript implicitly "boxes" the primitive in an object instance.

Comment: `if (Object.prototype.toString.call(object) === "[object Object]")` http://jsfiddle.net/15snrunw/1/

Comment: re: edit: use `42..tablify()` (the first dot is parsed as decimal point) or `(42).tablify()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is `typeof` always returning `"object"`?

Because in sloppy mode, the [`this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) always is supposed to be an object. When you call a function or pass undefined or null, you get the global object, when you call a method the context will get casted to an object.

Use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) for your `tablify` method and it will work!

> Is it a good thing for a JS-API to provide this sort of functionality (extending Arrays/Objects with `.tablify();`)?

[Yes.](http://sugarjs.com/native) [No.](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/). Many people will frown to use your script when you want to share it. See [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572) for a detailed discussion.

At least you've [properly used non-enumerable properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13296897/1048572) - but I would recommend to use them on `Array.prototype` as well, too many people abuse `for in` enumerations.

> How is it possible to distinguish between "normal" objects, numbers, functions,... ?

`typeof` seems fine.

> Is it possible to only extend "normal" objects? (forbid (42).tablify();, "string".tablify(); ...)

Not really. All primitive wrappers inherit from `Object.prototype`.

> Whats the name for those "normal" objects? How should I call them?

Just "objects". Or "plain objects" if you want (distinguishes them from arrays, built-ins, host objects).

Comment: Thanks, that was really informative. I got it working using strict mode, though I'll remove that functionality since the advantage is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you get into your newly-added method on the prototype, the original primitive value has already been converted. For example:

```
"foo".tablify();
```

In that call, *before* the function is called, the string primitive is converted into a String instance. In other words, it behaves as if you had written:

```
new String("foo").tablify();
```

I suppose you could use the `Object.prototype.toString` function to tell the difference:

```
function  tablify(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === "object") {
      var sig = {}.toString.call(obj);
      if (/ (String|Number|Boolean)\]$/.test(sig)) {
        // treat as primitive
      }
      else {
        // object
      }
    }
    // ...
}
```

You won't be able to tell if the boxed primitive was implicitly created or not, but that probably doesn't really matter for what your code does anyway.