# SCOPE - Get elements by classname and call a Jquery prototype function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to adapt a videoplayer to meet my needs (resizing).

At this moment almost everything is ok, but I have a problem when 2 or more players are showed in the same page (the jquery reference is always pointing to the last player).

To fix it, I'm trying to use jquery selector:

```
$('className').each(function() { /* call resize function */ } );
```

Now I have a problem because I can call resize function using `MyObject1.resize();` but the selector only returns `div` tags (`id="obj1"`, `id="obj2"`) and I don't now how can I get `MyObject1`, `MyObject2` and so on, so I could call resize function for every object.

So, how can I call a function defined like `Object.prototype.resize = function() {...}` from the jquery selector each loop?

UPDATE ****************

Hi, thanks for all your replies, Im not an js expert, sorry :)

Im trying to adapt leanback HTML5 Video Player which js file start as :

```js
"use strict"
;(function(window, undefined) 
  {
var document = window.document, navigator = window.navigator, location = window.location, ua$ = navigator.userAgent;

var LBP = function(o, v, h5o) { ... };

LBP.prototype.initializeKeys = function() { ... }
...
LBP.prototype.initializeAPlayer = function() {
LBP.prototype.initializeVPlayer = function() {
  
LBP.prototype.resize = function() { .. }
```

I have 3 players in html (classname = "vPlayer") so I want to call the resize function from the three player, not only from the last.

Jquery Selectors returns something like div tags so I don't know how to call functions from the LBP objects

Comment: you should post how (*the code*) you initialize the players (*how you create/assign to `MyObject1`, `MyObject2` etc..*)

Comment: Try `$('.className')`

Comment: `Object.prototype.resize = ` is a [pretty bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Comment: What does this have to do with SCOPEs, and what "jQuery prototype functions" do you mean?

Comment: Thanks Bergi, but doing this way $('.className').resize()  I cannot reach LBP.resize method (undefined is not a function)