# How to assert partially deep equal/compare objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an API and I want to assert that at least the expected data is returned. I don't care if more data is returned.

Therefore I want to compare two objects (`expected` and `actual`) where all attributes of `expected` must be equal to `actual`, but `actual` may contain more attributes:

```
var expected = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: {
        x1: 42,
        a1: [
            1,
            2,
            {
                x: 7
            }
        ]
    }
}

var actual = {
    foo: 1,
    whatever: 55, // to be ignored
    additional: { // to be ignored
        ignore: 1
    },
    bar: {
        x1: 42,
        a1: [
            1,
            2,
            {
                x: 7,
                y: 8   // to be ignored
            }
        ]
    }
}

partiallyEqual(expected, actual) // returns true
```

Some more examples:

```
partiallyEqual({x: 1}, {a:2, x:1}) // return true
partiallyEqual({x: 1}, {a:2, x:2}) // return false (x is different)
```

Arrays may (optionally) be subject to partial equivalent, if `actual` contains additional elements.

```
partiallyEqual([1, 3], [1, 2, 3]) // return true
partiallyEqual([3, 1], [1, 2, 3]) // return false (different order)
```

Comment: Have you tried Chai's `deepEqual`?

Comment: yes, but it is a strict equal, id does not ignore any attributes

Comment: Since your use case is a little variation of `deepEqual`, I would suggest to look here:https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql/blob/master/lib/eql.js      
Tweak it a little bit for your need.

Comment: A potential solution may be to create a copy of `actual` that strips all attributes that are not in `expected` before comparing.

Comment: For a small object that could be correct but if the object is huge then it might not be the best solution.

Comment: @Michael_Scharf Tried utilizing `Object.keys()` , `Array.prototype.some` ?

Comment: why just not go only by properties from expected and check value for same key in two objects??

Answer (score 0):

Deep equal can be tricky for varies cases, for example `NaN !== NaN` and there could be circular references. I wrote a simple deep equal check util function with recursive and circular reference check recently, and it should be pretty straight forward to follow. You can simply ignore some of the length check to have the partially equal done.

Source code on github: https://github.com/ryancat/simple-deep-equal

Answer (score -1):

I use this recursive function, that I wrote some time ago:

```
Object.prototype.equals = function(to) {
    for (var prop in to) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop) && to.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (to[prop] && typeof this[prop] == "object" && typeof to[prop] == "object") {
                if (!this[prop].equals(to[prop])) {
                    return false
                }
            } else if (this[prop] != to[prop]) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
};

({ x: { a: 1, b: 2 } }).equals({ x: { a: 1, b: 2 } }) => true
({ x: { a: 1, b: 2 } }).equals({ x: { a: 1, b: 1 } }) => false
({ x: [1,2] }).equals({ x: { 1:1,2:2 } }) => true (doesn't differentiate between array and/or object)
```

This function will return false as soon as it finds some difference in old vs new object. The new object can contain anything, if it have all the properties of the old object.

Comment: Please see [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13296897/1048572) and do your `Object.prototype` extension properly.

Comment: I use function named prop that does it: function prop(to, name, func) {
    `Object.defineProperty(to.prototype, name, {
        value: func,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return func;
}`

it is used as fallow
    `prop(Object, 'equals', function (to) {...})`
these can be chained:
    `prop(Object, 'equals', function (to) {prop(Array, 'equals', function (to) {...})})`

And by the way, extending object extends Array too, as it extends EVERYTHING