# How does inheritance work in ES5-Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

For the below code,

```
           var customer={
                name: "Tom Smith",

                speak: function(){
                    return "My name is " + this['name'];
                },

                address: {
                    street: '123 Main St',
                    city: "Pittsburgh",
                    state: "PA"
                }
            };
```

Below is my visualisation of customer object,

---

### [image]

My question:

Does `customer` object inherit properties(built-ins) of `Object.prototype` only?

Are the properties(built-ins) of `Object` function type object are also for the purpose of inheritance?

If yes, What is the syntax for `customer` object to inherit `Object` properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does JavaScript .prototype work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572897/how-does-javascript-prototype-work)

Comment: Anyhow, objects don't really inherit properties so much as they have a prototype chain of objects which property access will traverse.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara the suggested answer use `[[Prototype]]`, which in my case, `customer.[[Prototype]]` is `Object.prototype`. But my question is, Does JS allow `customer` inherit `Object` properties as well? Is this a duplicate query?

Comment: Oh, you mean you the static-like methods of the Object constructor? They are not inherited, and normally you wouldn't need to do this, they are globally accessible.

Comment: @overexchange how did you make that visualization?

Comment: @zer00ne Using `msword` and `mspaint`. I still missed `Function` object, which is not relevant here. Any reason for this question? I have such visualisations on OOJS [here](https://github.com/shamhub/Javascript_Programming/tree/master/Topic7_WorkingWithObjects).

Comment: @overexchange I have trouble trying to explain things to my boss sometimes and hoping it was from a program not talent :P It would take me forever to produce quality like that.

Comment: @overexchange Watched, starred, & forked, thank you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Below is my visualisation of customer object

It would be better if you used the term *[[prototype]]* instead of *__proto__* - as you can see, `.__proto__` is just a getter/setter inherited from `Object.prototype`.

> Does customer object inherit properties(built-ins) of `Object.prototype` only?

Yes. Though you could [add your own properties to `Object.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572), they would be inherited as well, it's not only the built-in ones.

> Are the properties(built-ins) of Object are also for the purpose of inheritance?

No. They're static functions that are supposed to be called with objects as their arguments, not object methods.

> What is the syntax for customer object to inherit Object properties?

`Object` is a function and usually you don't *want* to inherit from it. If you really wanted, you could use `Object.create(Object)`.

Also, ES6 adds a new way to do that, as `class`es inherit static methods from their parent as well:

```
class MyObject extends Object {
    static myCreate(x) {
        return this.create(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any mistake in above screenshot? apart from `[[Prototype]]` naming convention?

Comment: @overexchange: `Customer` should be `customer`. And you definitely need to do something about the arrows, though that's only a usability concern not one of correctness

Comment: Arrows? I did not get u.

Comment: I found those arrows between the boxes to be very hard to decipher visually. Those two crossings, uh, it's only one, and the merge, look too similar…

Comment: After your suggestions, Is [this](https://github.com/shamhub/Javascript_Programming/blob/master/Topic7_OOJS/OOJS/objectliteral.png) fine now?

Comment: Thanks, those do look better now.