# javascript Ajax method in different browser has different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a code like this :

```
var width = [];

$.ajax({
   url : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx" ,
   type : "Get",
   dataType: "json",
   async   : true,
   success : function(data){
       for (var index in data)
       {
           var options = data[index].option;
           var position = (++index);
           width[index] = new Array();
           for (var keys in options)
           {
              width[index][keys] = options[keys].votes;
           }
       }
   }
});
```

in the chrome browser, it works fine, but in the safari, the error look likes:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'width[index][keys] = options[keys].votes')
```

But if I open debug mode in safari, there is no error, so what's the problem in this code?

Comment: Are you saying that the error disappears if you open the debug tools in safari?  Or just that there's no other additional error being reported?

Comment: Once, you use jQuery why do you mix it with pure javascrtipt? Just a question.

Comment: @lolka_bolka jQuery is JavaScript. Why would you replace any of their "pure JavaScript" stuff with jQuery helpers? All they're using is a couple of for-in loops.

Comment: What kind of data is options[keys].votes?

Comment: Probably you've got some polyfills in Safari? See [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Comment: Start off with iterating arrays with a regular for loop ([no for..in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)).

Comment: If i open debug tools in safari, thers is no error and no other additional error being reported, but If I close the debug tools and refresh, the error will appears.

Comment: You're incrementing the loop counter inside the loop (`++index`).  Don't do that.

Comment: What does `data` contain?  Please provide an example.

Comment: As @Archer pointed out - you are incrementing your loop variable `index` while using it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my for loop code like this:

```
    for (var index = 0;index < data.length;index++) {
        var options = data[index].option;
        var position = index + 1;
        width[index] = new Array();
        for (var keys = 0; keys < options.length; keys++) {
            width[index][keys] = options[keys].votes;
        }
    }
```

there is no error in any browser.