# Object Prototype Function Breaking in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, prototype

Someone helped me with a great object prototype for JavaScript but it breaks in jQuery.  In jQuery it gives an error:

jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: V[g].exec is not a function

I found that the Object.defineProperty block (below) stops the jQuery error.  But then it doesn't work.  When I call to multiparter() it just returns "undefined". Can anyone help with a solution?

```
Object.prototype.multiparter = function(route) {
    var newObj = this;
    route.forEach(function(key) {
        newObj = newObj[key]
    });
    return newObj;
};

Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'multiparter',{
    value : function() {},
    enumerable : false
});

var mekBldr = {
    mecha: {
        heads: {
            head01: {
                cost: 0,
                classification: ''
            }
        },
        rightLimbs: {
            legs: {
                rightleg01: {
                    cost: 0,
                    classification: ''
                }
            }
        },
        leftLimbs: {
            legs: {
                leftleg01: {
                    cost: 0,
                    classification: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var part = 'heads';
var stuck2 = [part];
var part1 = 'leftLimbs';
var part2 = 'legs';
var stuck = [part1, part2];
mekBldr.mecha.multiparter(stuck2).head01.cost = 2;
//goal: mekBldr.mecha.leftLimbs.legs.leftleg01.cost = 5;
mekBldr.mecha.multiparter(stuck).leftleg01.cost = 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing a `value` to the descriptor, you've just overwritten the method with that empty function (which is the one doing nothing and returning `undefined`). If you really want to [define a method on `Object.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572) (which you absolutely should not do), you'd need to use

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, 'multiparter', {
    value: function(route) {
        return route.reduce(function(newObj, key) {
            return newObj[key]
        }, this);
    },
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It sounds like I shouldn't solve my problem by using Object.prototype.  What is a better solution?  Towards the bottom of my code sample above, you can see "goal".  That's what I'm trying to accomplish.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make it a static function: `multiparter(mekBldr.mecha, stuck2).head01.cost` not a method. One day you'd encounter an object that had its own `multiparter` property, and your code would break.

Comment: Like this?
`code`function multiparter(theObj,route) {
    route.forEach(function (key) {
        theObj = theObj[key]
    });
    return theObj;
}`code`

Comment: @user1592980 Yes, exactly. Though I recommend to use `reduce` instead of `forEach` like in my answer :-)