# Can For-In loop result an undefined or null?

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

This is my code:

```
const a = function(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    console.info(key.split('_'));
  }
};
a({a_b: 123});
```

I thought there is no problem at all but SonarQube gives me a critical error:

> TypeError can be thrown as "key" might be null or undefined here.

The word **key** in **key.split('_')** is highlighted. Indicating variable key can be undefined/null here.

I tried to pass in something like `{[undefined]: 123}`, and the variable **key** becomes a string "undefined" instead of real undefined.

Hence. I am wondering will the key be undefined/null in any possible situation? Or is it just a False Positive?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Picture]

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ That was a typo, the console.info is inside the for loop and the error still exists.

Comment: `key` is defined at updated Question. Not certain what you are trying to determine?

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe there's a bug in SonarQube. I've never worked with it. Keys in objects are always strings, so there's no way `key` become `undefined`.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ `{}` would have an `undefined` key. Or, at least log `undefined` at `console` if passed to `for..in`.

Comment: @guest271314 no, that's just the output of the command as it gets evaluated by console.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ  What is occurring at `for (let j in {}) console.log(j)` ?

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ `console.log()` is not reached?

Comment: @guest271314 try `for (let j in {}) console.log('x:'+j)`, see what you got.

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ, ooops :)

Comment: @Aᴍɪʀ He already deleted them... Anyway, thanks for indicating the fact that "Keys in objects are always strings". I definitely read that sentence somewhere else before and now I just recognized it. It should be a bug of SonarQube then.

Comment: The actual bug in your code is the [`obj.hasOwnProperty` call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13296897/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi Why that is a bug?

Comment: @SCLeo Because it doesn't work if your object has an `hasOwnProperty` property (which is usually more probably than `obj` inheriting some enumerable properties). It needs to be `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj)`, or you should just omit it completely.

Comment: @Bergi Please, please don't give SonarQube more ideas about things to complain about.

Comment: @Bergi Oh yea, that is true... But I don't think I will ever have that problem. The reason I add hasOwnProperty here is to prevent prototype pollution...

Comment: @torazaburo Actually, that would be one good thing more linters should complain about :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a [known bug](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJS-734) in the SonarQube JavaScript analyser which was fixed a few months ago. You should upgrade to the latest version of the JavaScript plugin.