# Create a prototype function for adding style to element

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I want to create a prototype function for adding style to element.
Similar to the following code:

```js
element.css3("property" , "value");
```

please help me to write prototype function.
this is my code : (has problems)

```js
Object.prototype.css3 = function (property , value) {
  this.style.property = value;
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't modify builtins, but if you absolutely have to, at least [do it properly please](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to set a property using a string variable otherwise which sets a property named `property`. Where use [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to capitalize character after `-` symbol, to make valid property in Javascript style.

```
Element.prototype.css3 = function (property , value) {
  this.style[property.replace(/-([a-z])/gi,function(_,m){ return m.toUpperCase(); })] = value;
  // or this.style[property] = value;
};
```

Comment: @hamidreza :  because dot notation sets a property named as `property` not the string value passed .... for set using a string , use bracket notation

Comment: can you write a code for delete ' - ' characters and capital next character?for exam: background-color => backgroundColor

Comment: I knew nothing of this Code . /-([a-z])/gi,function(_,m){ return m.toUpperCase(); }

Comment: @hamidreza :  which is using to replace the character

Comment: I really need to learn more about this notation: `/-([a-z])/`. I have seen it used, but not sure what it is called.

Comment: @xxSithRagexx :  it's regex

Comment: @hamidreza :  it's called regex , for matching certain pattern.... in above example which matches - followed by any character

Comment: @hamidreza : the character-class is wrapped using parenthesis ( capturing-group ).... which can be accessed as the second argument in callback... within the callback capitalizing the value and replacing

Comment: Okay, I am up to speed on `regex`, pretty awesome. The use case in this script makes perfect sense now. Only part I am not clear on is your arguments in the function. `m` is clearly the letter after the `-` character, but how was it passed to the function? Thanks for your input on this!

Comment: @xxSithRagexx :  rest will do by the `replace` method

Comment: wow!! if i remove method replace for css (writed by :Pranav C Balan) , code works too. for exam elemnt.css3('background-color' , 'red'); really background color be red!!!

Comment: @hamidreza : yes it will work, camecase is using to work with dot notation

Comment: @xxSithRagexx : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Comment: @PranavCBalan: Thank you! Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve what you are trying to do is to write it like this:

```
Object.prototype.css3 = function (property , value) {
  this.style[property] = value;
};
```

The way it is written now it will be looking for the `[property]` named property of `[style]`, which does not exist. With this you will be able to pass a string form of the property to the style and change your value.