# JavaScript: why I get false instead of true in my code of property owner searching?

Tags: javascript

I learn JavaScript and play with it. Why I get `false` instead of `true` in my code of property owner searching? What is my mistake?

```
/* Get the object containing the property. */
Object.prototype.where = function (propName){ return this.hasOwnProperty(propName) ? this :
    (this.constructor.prototype ? null : this.where.bind(this.constructor.prototype, propName)());};

let a = {foo : 123}, b = Object.create(a), c = a == b.where('foo');

process.stdout.write(c.toString()); // false
```

Comment: constructor will be *Object*

Comment: Consider not augmenting the Object prototype, when people do that it leads to global problems sometimes https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2015/string-prototype-contains-has-been-renamed-to-includes/

Comment: You may want https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf

Comment: [Don't define `Object.prototype` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)! At least make it a static `Object.where(obj, propName)` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a=Object.create(b);
//constructor: Object
//constructor.prototype: Object.prototype

//really inherits from: b

a = new b();
//constructor: b
//constructor.prototype: b.prototype

//really inherits from: b.prototype
```

Your code just works with constructor functions and the new operator, in all the other cases it goes wrong, as it does not inherit from the constructors prototype directly. It would be better to look up the prototype chain instead:

```
Object.where = function (obj,propName){ 
  return obj.hasOwnProperty(propName) ? 
   obj :
(!Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) ? null : Object.where(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), propName));
};

Object.where(Object.create({a:0}),"a");
```

Note that overriding Object.prototype is a bad idea, as it confuses all for loops. So one may set enumerable to false, or one simply make it static...

Comment: Why do you compare to `Object.prototype`? That doesn't allow things like `Object.where({}, "hasOwnProperty")`.

Answer (score 0):

Because `b.constructor.prototype != a`. You will want to use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to follow the prototype chain.