# How to avoid prototype pollution in javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

In javascript, it's possible to "override" properties or methods of `Object.prototype`. For example:

```
Object.prototype.toString = function(){
  return "some string";
};
```

It can break an entire application if not used carefully. Are there any tools, techniques or approaches to avoid this (for example, some kind of 'strict mode' that doesn't allow the developer to override properties of Object)?

Comment: Just don't do it and don't take in any libraries that do?

Comment: `Object.freeze(Object.prototype)` will help, but again.. don't know how much pollution it will create

Comment: A good read for anyone that lands on this question: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/object-freeze-object-prototype-vs-reality

Comment: @RayToal: **Fantastic** link, I've added it to the CW answer below.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572) on how to do this carefully and not break applications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Object.freeze(YourConstructor.prototype)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) can help protect *your* constructor's associated prototype object from being mucked with. From MDN:

> The `Object.freeze()` method freezes an object: that is, prevents new properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed, it also prevents the prototype from being changed.

It works on the object itself, rather than making a copy that's frozen. It returns the same reference you pass it.

It's best to leave built-in prototypes alone, so using it on `Object.prototype` and such may not be a great idea. :-) Certainly you'd need to do a **lot** of testing if you did... See [this thread](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/object-freeze-object-prototype-vs-reality) on the es-discuss mailing list for relevant, useful info.

Comment: hmm, but a simple thing I want to add (or may be ask), what is the point of doing this if some attack de-refer the `Object` itself?

Comment: @KoushikChatterjee These techniques only can help to prevent third parties from *accidentally* breaking your application. They never can *secure* it against an attacker. If you have anyone run unrestricted code on your page, you've already lost.

Comment: +1 because you can lock your doors but you can't put bear traps in your own house, that's not how security works.

Comment: @Bergi yeah that's the conceptual stuff about `XSS` , but the point of my comment was, is there any way further to prevent that (though we know, preventing XSS is not at all a good idea because its already too late)