# Only custom object properties are shown during for-in loop

Tags: javascript

```js
Array.prototype.myFeature = function() {};

var arr = ['some', 'items'];

for (var prop in arr) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

The output for that code will be: `0`, `1`, `myFeature`.

The question is: **why** only custom added function to the `Array` prototype is outputed, instead of all the function that exists in prototype?

Comment: Two things I wanted to point out: first that adding your own functions to native prototypes is considered bad practice, and that normal functions which accept the array as an argument should be preferred. Secondly, arrays shouldn't be looped over using `for..in`, only using `.forEach`, or a `for..of` loop, as, with `for..in`, the order can't be guaranteed, and you run into issues like this.

Comment: Related reading: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/710446) (it's slow, order is not preserved, and you get all enumerable properties)

Comment: @kingdaro completely agree with you, but it was just for testing. I wanted to know why is that happening.

Comment: Closely related: [How to define method in javascript on `Array.prototype` or `Object.prototype` so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because built-in array methods are defined to be non-enumerable, while properties created by ordinary assignment are enumerable. Internally, properties have behavioral features specified by their associated [*property descriptor*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) which is defined at property-creation time. One feature supplied in this way is the property's enumerability.

Compare

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, "join")
{value: ƒ, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true}
```

and

```
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Array.prototype, "myFeature")
{value: ƒ, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}
```

The first property descriptor object has `enumerable: false` while the second has `enumerable: true`. Non-enumerable properties are not enumerated in for-in loops.

You can define your own non-enumerable property with [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "myFeature", { value: function() {}, enumerable: false });
```

Answer (score 4):

Per the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> The `for...in` statement iterates over the [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) of an object. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

Seems, only these three properties are enumerable. So `for...in` only iterates over them.