# Add isEmpty to Array prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

I want to add a property to the object `Array`. I've been trying the following:

```
Array.prototype.isEmpty = array => (array || []).length <= 0 // only works if I use array.isEmpty(array) which isn't exactly what I want.

Array.prototype.isEmpty = (() => (this || []).length <= 0)() // always returns true since this is always undefined.
```

Is there a way to add this in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried `Array.prototype.isEmpty = function() { return (this ....` ?

Comment: Don't us arrow function syntax for methods. Btw, have a look at [How to define method in javascript on `Array.prototype` so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572)

Comment: Read [Why is extending native objects a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034180/why-is-extending-native-objects-a-bad-practice)

Comment: `Array.prototype.isEmpty = function() { return  !!this.length }`.

Comment: [When to/not use arrow functions](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=don%27t+use+arrow+functions+for+everything&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english).