# Can't declare a Object.prototype in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to create a custom function for objects in Next.js

I'm writting the following

```js
Object.prototype._something = function (something) {
   console.log(something)
}
```

It works, but now it gives me a weird error

```sh
Warning: Invalid value for prop `_something` on <img> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.
```

But it is only with Object.prototype, if I declare the same function as Array.prototype everything workds fine

Comment: I think the error arises from where you are using it. Are you using it with HTML tags anywhere? Please add tnhose details too

Comment: Usually unwise to directly edit prototypes in JS. Why not a util function?

Comment: Maybe have a look at [How to define method in javascript on Array.prototype and Object.prototype so that it doesn't appear in for in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13296340/1048572). But really, [don't put custom functions on `Object.prototype`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572)!