# This in addeventlistner property in javascript

Tags: javascript, this

I have seen come code which is related to `addEventListener` function and `this` keyword in JavaScript.

I know `this` refers to the global object and `addEventListener` registers the specified listener on the EventTarget it's called on.

```
var Something = function (element) {
  this.name = 'Something Good';
  this.onclick1 = function (event) {
    console.log(this.name);
  };
  this.onclick2 = function (event) {
    console.log(this.name);
  };
  element.addEventListener('click', this.onclick1, false);
  element.addEventListener('click', this.onclick2.bind(this), false);
}
```

Here I just need to know how the last line of this above script works:

```
element.addEventListener('click', this.onclick2.bind(this), false);
```

I understand what `bind` does -- I just need to know what do the two `this`s represents in `this.onclick2.bind(this)`. Do they represents element and event attributes, that is, is it acting like `element.onclick2.bind(event)`?

Comment: By creating a simple test case you'll find out.

Comment: I am not sure for the answer for addEventListener, in setTimeout case, I know the answer. And I'm pretty sure it is the same.

So, what is happening ? You give some argument to a method of element. So "this" represents "element", and not the instance of "Something".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17241781/is-it-better-to-bind-this-or-use-a-variable/17242228#17242228

Comment: @vekah so this represents the element variable  right here ?.

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure.
You should still try some tests on it.

For instance, if you were calling window.setTimeout instead of addEventListener, "this" would represent "window" and not the instance of your class "Something".

Answer (score 0):

```
this.onclick2.bind(this)
```

This piece of code returns the `onclick2` function with its `this` variable bound to the argument passed to `.bind()`, which is `this`, in this case.

For example:

```
function testing(parameter){
    console.log(parameter, this);
}
var boundFunction = this.testing.bind({ someKey: 'SomeValue'});
boundFunction("Testing 1 2 3");
```

Will log:

```
"Testing 1 2 3", {someKey: "SomeValue"}
```