# How does for loop index ascend the prototype chain?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Say I have an object `person` like so

```
var person = {
  firstname: 'Default',
  lastname: 'Default',
  getFullName: function() {
    return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
  }
}
```

I make a new object `john` and set its prototype to that of `person`

```
var john = {
  firstname: 'John',
  lastname: 'Doe'
}

john.__proto__ = person;
```

if I `console.log` `john`, I see a tree structure like so

[image]

where we see `getFullName` embedded under `__proto__`. Now here comes the surprise

```
for (var prop in john) {
  console.log(prop)
}
```

returns

[image]

Even though `getFullName` was one level deep, somehow, the loop was able to find it.

Now, compare that to

```
var obj = {a: 1, b: {c:2, d: 3 }}
for (var prop in obj) {console.log(prop)}
```

which behaves as I expect, which is that `c` and `d` were not automagically found by the loop

[image]

So how is it that in the former case the loop traversed deeper in to the tree to dig up embedded properties while in the latter it did not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: hiding prototype methods in for loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107681/javascript-hiding-prototype-methods-in-for-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for..in` loop will iterate all the own enumerable properties, as well as the inherited enumerable properties. That is why you are seeing `getFullName` in the loop.

But in the second case, it lists only the properties of `obj`, which are actually `a` and `b` only (`c` and `d` are properties of object `b`).

---

[This](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-forin-div-ofheadevaluation-tdznames-expr-iterationkind) is corresponding section from the language specification, for `for..in` and it uses the internal `[[Enumerate]]` slot.

The internal [`[[Enumerate]]`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate) slot will be used to enumerate the object passed to it which gives the enumerable properties of the object. Quoting that section,

> Enumerating the properties of the target object includes enumerating properties of its prototype, and the prototype of the prototype, and so on, recursively;

Since the `for..in` goes up the prototype chain recursively, we are able to see the objects defined in the prototype, in this case `getFullName`.

---

If you don't want the `getFullName` to show up during the iteration, then you can define it as non-enumerable, like this

```
var person = {
  firstname: 'Default',
  lastname: 'Default'
};

Object.defineProperty(person, 'getFullName', {
  value: function() {
    return this.firstname + ' ' + this.lastname;
  },
  enumerable: false
});
```

Now when you print the keys, `getFullName` will not be shown, as it is not enumerable anymore.

---

**Note:** Using `__proto__` should be avoided, as it is not part of the ECMAScript specifications. Instead, you should use `Object.setPrototypeOf`.